# How do I perform a regex match on a file

Tags: bash, regex

How do I perform a regex match on a file and output the result.

For example, find `version="X.Y.Z"` and store in a variable the matched result of X.Y.Z so as to be later able to echo the match.

The is as far as I've gotten on my own:
    sed -n -e 's/version\=\".*\"' $PATH"version.js"

My file contents are:

```
var config;
function check() {
    if (window.environment && window.revision) {
        config.version = "0.0.1";
        config.isApp = true;
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(check);
    }
}
check();
```

and I wish to store `0.0.1` in a variable as I wish to insert this value into another file.

Comment: Can you clarify what output you are piping (i assume) into sed ? Are the files you are searching in one folder ? is the version in the file name, or in the file itself ?

Comment: @kyze I have just one file which I wish to pipe in: $PATH"version.js"

Comment: Alright, so you are outputting the contents of the file and are regex-searching the contents ? Would a `cat version.js | grep ...` not do the trick in this case ?

Comment: @kyze I'm very new to bash so I will explore your suggestion, thanks!

Comment: If you give some example contents of the file, i (and others too) can assist.

Comment: I have updated my question @kyze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be working in your case:

`cat /path/to/version.js | grep config.version | grep -P -o '\d\.\d\.\d'`

If your number is ever gonna be double-digit (or more) you need to add a + to the \d corresponding to the number.

As `'\d\.\d\.\d'` matches `1.1.1, 1.1.2, 2.2.9` etc. it would not match `1.10.2`, then the regex would need to be modified to `'\d\.\d+\.\d'`.

You could go the "easy/safe" route and just put `'\d+\.\d+\.\d+'`.

The output of the first would just be your version number, which could be set to a variable after.

**As an edit to your comment:** 
This works correctly for me. I have created a file with your given inputs, grepping this with my command yields this:

[image]

Using this to set a variable as such, then echoing works as well:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help @kyze. I tried: temp=$(cat $BUILD_PATH"config.js" | grep config.version | grep -P -o '\d\.\d\.\d') echo $temp but it didn't work. I also tried temp=$(cat $BUILD_PATH"config.js" | grep config.version) and it outputs config.version = "0.0.1";

Comment: My grep is as follows: usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]

Comment: Ah it works if I remove the P flag and use asterisk instead of plus.

Comment: It works if you remove the `-P` ? This should not be happening, as standard grep can not interpret the \d regex and would need [[:digit:]]

Comment: Ok, weird. I'm using GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16). My grep is now $(cat $BUILD_PATH"config.js" | grep config.version | grep -o '\d*\.\d*\.\d*')

Comment: Alright, since this seems to be an apple product, this might actually be different. :) This would also have been a good info for you starting post.